# Linq to Entities Left outer join grouped into a collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
from component in Materials.OfType<Container>().Where(m => m.Active)
join segmentFinanceRating in segmentFinanceRatingView on component.Id equals segmentFinanceRating.MaterialId into segmentFinanceRatingGroup
from segmentFinanceRatingWithDefault in segmentFinanceRatingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
   id = component.Id,
   name = component.Name,
   subType = component.SubType,
   size = component.Size,
   MaterialIds = component.Materials.Select(x => x.Id),
   BrandNames = component.Brands.Select(x => x.Name),
   SegmentRatings = segmentFinanceRatingWithDefault
}
```

I have the above LINQ to Entities query that has a `LEFT JOIN` to get rating values for 1 or more segments for a given component.

The `segmentFinanceRating` entity has the properties, `{ MaterialId, SegmentId, Rating, LowRated }`

At the moment the results are not grouped to the relevant component, i.e. the `SegmentRatings` property is not a single collection of `segmentFinanceRating` objects, instead I have multiple data rows with 1 `segmentFinanceRating` object in each.

I have seen some examples of using `group x by y into z` but I couldn't get it working, possibly due to some of the collections on the component that I need too, I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated on how to do this, thanks.

Comment: I didnt have a lot of time for this and I got most of the way there with the grouping but adding the collection properties into it wasn't working out.. I opted for breaking these queries up and then using linq to objects instead and caching the result but if anyone has an answer to this I would like to see it

Answer (score 1):

GroupBy in List doesn't work for you?

```
var list = (from component in Materials.OfType<Container>().Where(m => m.Active)
join segmentFinanceRating in segmentFinanceRatingView on component.Id equals segmentFinanceRating.MaterialId into segmentFinanceRatingGroup
from segmentFinanceRatingWithDefault in segmentFinanceRatingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
   id = component.Id,
   name = component.Name,
   subType = component.SubType,
   size = component.Size,
   MaterialIds = component.Materials.Select(x => x.Id),
   BrandNames = component.Brands.Select(x => x.Name),
   SegmentRatings = segmentFinanceRatingWithDefault
}).ToList().GroupBy(s=> s.SegmentRatings);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's much easier to do the join in the anonymous type:

```
from component in Materials.OfType<Container>().Where(m => m.Active)
select new
{
   id = component.Id,
   name = component.Name,
   subType = component.SubType,
   size = component.Size,
   MaterialIds = component.Materials.Select(x => x.Id),
   BrandNames = component.Brands.Select(x => x.Name),
   SegmentRatings = (from segmentFinanceRating in segmentFinanceRatingView
                     where segmentFinanceRating.MaterialId == component.Id
                     select segmentFinanceRating)
}
```

You will have an empty collection of `SegmentRatings` when there are none for a specific component, giving the same effect as outer join.